# Storing data from a form and display this data per user

Tags: database

I'm currently building a website where registrated users must have the possibility to log there sports training data throughout a form that has to be filled in after every training.

After that the specific user has to have the possibility to get an overview of his training logs and see charts and an overall summary of all his training data he filled in using the form on the website.

How do i have to establish that? I don't expect you give me the code but can somebody tell me the basic principles for establishing that so i can search the world wide web further.

Do i have to create different databases that communicate with eachother? If so how does this call? ( so i can search for the good search term)

I already found out to create a form and store this data in a database but i only can display the overall data on the website and not the data specific per user and that is what i need.

Thx

Comment: You need to learn how to build Web application, that support user registration, database, and much more.. there are frameworks for this, e.g http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0):

What you need to work on now is DB Table design and SQL.

You would not be creating separate databases but different tables in a single database. Learn about normalizing the tables *(First normal form, 2nd NF, 3rd NF)*. That would guide you on how to break your data into different tables so that you can *join* them in various ways to generate *data views* that would back your graphs, charts etc.

Structure Query Language (SQL) is what would let you query your database to fetch a subset of the data mine stored at the backend. For example, querying data for just one user, or query data for all the users but just for the current month so that users could compare their progress etc.

The process of querying and displaying the data would more or less remain the same. Just the SQL would change as per your application's requirements for a particular page.

Take look at this easy beginner's [SQL tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-select-statement.htm).

***EDIT** : (response to OP's comments)*

One of the signs of good database design is that it doesn't change much when the scope the application increases. Now, you're right when you say you need a new table to cover different types of *sports* but I would suggest to have another table for the *users* as well.

I'm getting the idea that you're think about your user as just a username/id to fetch all the stats for but think about the possibilities if you collate more data about them. Like email if a user is interested in getting his weekly progress reports or say top 10 users this month and where s/he stands among the peers. Or, a Twitter handle to tweet any time a user beats his personal best or achieves a goal. Possibilities are endless.

Now, it's likely your current scope doesn't include all that but down the line when you would want to implement something like that; refactoring your tables would be hard and error prone. More the data you're dealing with, the bigger the risk.

Comment: Thank you for the info. The form that has to be filled in and finally will be the data in the database contains following data:date of training, type of sport, distance(km), duration, heart rate, feeling/mood of the day. Will different tables be usefull ? Only for the data 'type of sports' a different table could be very usefull because they wiil be the same for different users but the rest is very user specific and will always be different or am i wrong?